# WiX: "PushButton: 'Next' of Dialog: 'InstallDirDlg' does not have an event defined in the ControlEvent table. It is a 'Do Nothing' button."

Tags: wix, wix3.8

I have a WiX 3.8 installer `Product.wxs` that builds correctly in Visual Studio 2010 Professional.
I just wanted to modify the steps workflow of the installer, so I added this just after the Wix/Product/Package XML element:

```
<UI>
  <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg"
           Control="Next"
           Event="NewDialog"
           Value="InstallDirDlg"
           Order="2">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg"
           Control="Back"
           Event="NewDialog"
           Value="WelcomeDlg"
           Order="2">1</Publish>
</UI>
```

Problem: WiX now fails with this message:

> Error 13  ICE17: PushButton: 'Next' of Dialog: 'InstallDirDlg' does not have an event defined in the ControlEvent table. It is a 'Do Nothing' button. C:\src\wix38\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\InstallDirDlg.wxs   14  1   Installer

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need a reference to the WiX UI you are modifying. Try this:

```
<UI>
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />        <!-- Added line -->

  <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg"
           Control="Next"
           Event="NewDialog"
           Value="InstallDirDlg"
           Order="2">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg"
           Control="Back"
           Event="NewDialog"
           Value="WelcomeDlg"
           Order="2">1</Publish>
</UI>
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to integrate InstallDirDlg to custom UI so I copied and modified **Publish** statements from [WixUI_InstallDir.wxs](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/master/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/WixUI_InstallDir.wxs#L58) source code.

Answer (score 0):

This is for all the people who are running into the same error but using the "WixSharp" libraries.
You can use the below sample code. Hope it helps!

```
public void GenerateMSI()
{
    //generic setup code
    Project project =
        new Project("myinstaller.msi",
            new Dir(@"d:\deployhere\", new Files(@"c:\mybuildfilesarehere\")),
            new Dir(@"d:\deployheretoo\", new Files(@"c:\mybuildfilesarehere\")));
    project.ProductId = new Guid();
    project.GUID = new Guid();

    //#1
    project.UI = WUI.WixUI_InstallDir; 

    //#2 - this will error without #1 (Exepected Error: @3, see below.)
    project.CustomUI =
new DialogSequence()
   .On(NativeDialogs.WelcomeDlg, Buttons.Next,
       new ShowDialog(NativeDialogs.InstallDirDlg))
   .On(NativeDialogs.InstallDirDlg, Buttons.Back,
       new ShowDialog(NativeDialogs.WelcomeDlg));

    Compiler.BuildMsi(project);
}
```

@3 - ErrorMessage: error LGHT0204 : ICE17: PushButton: 'Next' of Dialog: 'InstallDirDlg' does not have an event defined in the ControlEvent table. It is a 'Do Nothing' button.
//ICE17: PushButton: 'ChangeFolder' of Dialog: 'InstallDirDlg' does not have an event defined in the ControlEvent table. It is a 'Do Nothing' button.